# Ruby Table Data Structure to PL/SQL

Tags: ruby, oracle, plsql, datatable, jruby

Is there a way in Ruby to populate a table of data that would then be passed to a stored procedure?

Essentially what I'm trying to do is something like the below, but not entirely sure how to populate a table data record in Ruby.

```
def populate_record(data)

  record = {}

  data.each do |val|
  record = {
    :id           => val[:id],
    :order_number => val[:order_number]
  }

  end
end
```

So `record` would be my table of data and would contain several rows of data with multiple columns. This structure would match my table record in the PL/SQL stored procedure.

Any suggestions how to do this correctly in Ruby?

Comment: Why are you repeatedly assigning to the same variable? You probably mean `map`.

Comment: @tadman How would that look?

Comment: `records = data.map { | val| ... }` instead using [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-map).

Comment: `records = data.map { | k, v | { k.to_sym => v } }`

Comment: So would this end up giving me a table of data that had key value pairs?

Comment: What does `data` look like? Unless it's a Hash that won't be happening. You need to be more specific about what you're receiving here, and what you want your method to return.

Comment: Data will be something like:

Comment: `id: 123, order_number: 9570`, etc. So a table of data with key value pairs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136285/discussion-between-andrew-and-tadman).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to transform data like that, then try this:

```
data.map do |record|
  [ record[:id], record[:order_number ]
end.to_h
```

Where that should produce a Hash with the `:id` value as the key and the `:order_number` as the value.